# jQuery filtering negative numbers and making them positive

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm trying to produce a position change table which finds values less than zero, makes those values red, adds a class to activate a down arrow, and removes the minus sign from the negative values.

Everything works except I can't remove the minus sign. I have tried multiplying by -1 and Math.abs(), but nothing works. I'm not getting errors in the console either.

The values are being populated from csv data.

```
$('.move').filter(function() {
    var neg = $(this).text() < 0;
    return Math.abs(neg);
}).css( "color", "#ff0000" ).addClass('down');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the variable "neg" is a boolean. try : "return Math.abs($(this).text())"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried explicitly parsing the `$(this).text()` to a number, using `parseInt`?

Edit:

By the way, your filter is wrong you should do

```
$('.move').filter(function() {
    var number = $(this).text();
    var isNeg = number < 0;
    $(this).text(isNeg ? Math.abs(number) : number);
    return isNeg;
}).css( "color", "#ff0000" ).addClass('down');
```

Comment: Hi Giovane, this issue i'm not having is, it is treating the number as a positive, therefore adding an up arrow and text is green. Is there a way to return isNeg after the css has been assigned?

Comment: Thanks Giovane, I ended up setting the default css to the 'up' styles, so this code works perfectly. I just had to add a script for the 'no change', ie zero values which was easy. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the text returned by `text()` first using `parseInt` (to convert the string value into a number):

```
$('.move').filter(function() {

    // This filter function will keep only negative integers
    var val = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    return !isNaN(val) && val < 0;

}).css( "color", "#ff0000" ).addClass('down');
```

If you want to remove the negative sign, you'll need to change the text of every element that passed your filter function. However, removing the '-' sign will change the behavior of your filter function if run twice or more (negative numbers now appear as positive numbers), so beware of that.

```
... .addClass('down').each(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace('-', ''));
});
```

Comment: `...addClass('down').text(function(i,t) { return t.replace('-',''); });` for brevity.

Comment: Hi Bryan and David, I'm finding like Giovane's solution above, the final result, while a positive number, is triggering my >0 script which adds an up arrow and green text. So for those who have dropped positions I actually have green text, and both a red arrow and a green arrow as it's first adding the 'down' class then reevaluating and then adding am 'up' class.